# Optimize SELECT ... WHERE IN (...)

Tags: mysql, performance, memcached

I'm receiving a sequence of product IDs from external system. I have to show the product information preserving the sequence.

I'm using the following select to do so:

```
SELECT * FROM  products
WHERE  prodid in (10331,11639,12127..) ORDER BY Field(prodid, 10331,11639,12127...);
```

Sequence can consist of 20 IDs. prodid has b-tree index.

It's very frequent query, and I'm trying to find ways to improve performance of that part of the system. Now the average time for this query is 0.14-0.2 sec
I would like decrease time to 0.01-0.05 sec.

What is the best way to do so? MySQL HASH index, store product id in memcached, or something else?

Comment: What's the data type of the `prodid` column?  Usually how many product ids are in the `IN` clause?

Comment: prodid is INT (prodid < 100 000), IN usually consist of 20 IDs.

Comment: Is there any additional relation between data chosen by direct IDs? The bottleneck might be in jumping over a (presumably large) DB 20 times per query for selecting tiny bits of data, so clustering it by some other parameter might be an option.

Comment: No, there is no relations with other tables. The table and the SELECT are simple as they shown. The external system does all the hard job - I just need to select these IDs and show the product information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM  products                         <<-- select * is non-optimal
WHERE  prodid in (10331,11639,12127..) 
ORDER BY Field(prodid, 10331,11639,12127...);   <<-- your problem is here
```

First put an index on `prodid` see @Anthony's answer.

Than change the query to read:

```
SELECT only,the,fields,you,need FROM  products
WHERE  prodid in (10331,11639,12127..) 
ORDER BY prodid
```

If you make sure your `IN` list is sorted ascending before offering it to the `IN` clause, the `order by prodid` will yield the same result als `order by field(...`

- Using a function instead of a field kills any chance of using an index, causing slowness.
- `select *` will fetch data you may not need, causing extra disk access, and extra memory usage and extra network traffic.
- On InnoDB, if you only `select` indexed fields, MySQL will never read the table, but only the index saving time *(in your case this is probably not an issue though)*

> What is the best way to do so? MySQL HASH index, store product id in memcached, or something else?

There are a few tricks you can use.

- If the products table is not too big, you can make it a `memory` table, which is stored in RAM. Don't do this for big tables, it will slow other things down.
  You can only use `hash` indexes on memory tables.
- If the prodid's are continuous, you can use `BETWEEN 1000 AND 1019` instead of 
  `IN (1000, 1001 ..., 1019)`

Comment: Actually, ORDER BY Field - is not a function, it's MySQL's internal construction for setting output order. It's a method of preserving output order only. If I skip this construction, product information will be shown in a random order.

Comment: @Andre, you are mistaken, see the last edit in my post. Always use a columnname in an `order by` clause and never a function. Field() is a function, see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field  _(note the word `function` in the url)_

Comment: I can't sort IDs ascending or somehow - I have to preserve the order of products in line. To be honest, I'm not selecting all the fields using *. So, as a conclusion - I have to remove "order by field" and make ordering in my software?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to create a union of results:

```
SELECT * FROM  products WHERE prodid = 10331
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM  products WHERE prodid = 11639
UNION ALL
.
.
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM  products WHERE prodid = 12127
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting an index on the `prodid` column by using the following query:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON products (prodid);
```

For more info, read [this post.](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-index.htm)

Comment: prodid already has b-tree index, I have mentioned this moment