# When using multiple whereHas() for same table and column (taggables.title). execution time increases 40 times

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using whereHas(), to match restaurant dishes with multiple tags. 
While matching just one tag, it works fine, but for multiple tags, execution time increases.
What could be the reason of that?

I've tried two methods,
using multiple whereHas()

```
App\Dish
        ::whereHas('tags', function($q) {
                return $q->where('title','tag1');
        })
        ->whereHas('tags', function($q) {
                return $q->where('title','tag2');
        });
```

using one whereHas and combine all tags

```
App\Dish
        ::whereHas('tags', function($q) {
                return $q->whereIn('title',['tag1','tag2']);
        },'=',2);
```

I've tried indexing taggables table (tag_id and taggable_id)

Comment: have you tried indexing the title column? could help on finding the correct tags

Comment: Martin, no, but probable the problem isn't title, because for one tag, it doesn't take that much time

Comment: it is an approach to optimize whereIn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551288/optimize-select-where-in

Comment: I think indexing helped it with separate whereHas()

Answer (score 1):

The reasons of that was, that taggables table fields (tag_id, taggable_id and taggable_type) wasn't indexed